# Bash echo some lines to terminal and some lines to file

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have this code bash code called `xyz_to_mol`:

```
CARBONS=$(grep -ow "C" $1 | wc -l)
HYDROGENS=$(grep -ow "H" $1 | wc -l)
OXYGENS=$(grep -ow "O" $1 | wc -l)

ATYPES=0
ARRAY=($CARBONS $HYDROGENS $OXYGENS)

for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do
        if [ $i -gt 0 ]; then
                ((ATYPES+=1))
        fi
done

echo "Choose co0, co1 or co2 basis set"
read BASIS_SET

echo "BASIS"
echo "$BASIS_SET"
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Atomtypes="$ATYPES" Generators=0 Integrals=1.00D-15 Angstrom"
echo "Charge=6.0 Atoms="$CARBONS""
grep "C" $1
echo "Charge=1.0 Atoms="$HYDROGENS""
grep "H" $1
if [ $OXYGENS -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Charge=8.0 Atoms="$OXYGENS""
    grep "O" $1
fi
```

This works just as I want except for one thing: The line `"Choose co0, co1 or co2 basis set"` should not be written to output file but instead as an instruction to the command line for the user. So If I use the script like this:

```
xyz_to_mol ketone.xyz > ketone.mol
```

the user should see an instruction: `"Choose co0, co1 or co2 basis set"`. Then he or she should write `co0`, `co1` or `co2` and the output file `ketone.mol` should not contain the line `"Choose co0, co1 or co2 basis set"`. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompts are typically written to standard error, not standard output. You can do that explicitly:

```
echo "Choose co0, co1 or co2 basis set" >&2
read BASIS_SET
```

or implicitly with the `-p` option to `read`:

```
read -p "Choose co0, co1, or co2 basis set" BASIS_SET
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to send the file name as a parameter and write to the output file inside your script instead:

```
echo "BASIS" > $2
echo "$BASIS_SET" >> $2
echo "" >> $2
echo "" >> $2
echo "Atomtypes="$ATYPES" Generators=0 Integrals=1.00D-15 Angstrom" >> $2
echo "Charge=6.0 Atoms="$CARBONS"" >> $2
grep "C" $1 >> $2
echo "Charge=1.0 Atoms="$HYDROGENS"" >> $2
grep "H" $1 >> $2
if [ $OXYGENS -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Charge=8.0 Atoms="$OXYGENS"" >> $2
    grep "O" $1 >> $2
fi
```

And call the script like:

```
xyz_to_mol ketone.xyz ketone.mol
```